# My function doesn't memorize the head of linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have to do a program of a linked list with many function like delete, add and modify number.

In my code when I put a number in my function with the choice 1, after that when I want to display all the numbers I put the head in parameter but I see in visual studio that the parameter of the function don't have anything. What can I do in order to pass the head of the linked list in parameter in my function `Displaynbr`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Mynbr
{
    int nbr;
    struct Mynbr* next;
} typedef Mynbr;

void Menu();
void choiceMenu(int choice, Mynbr* first);
Mynbr* Addnumber(Mynbr* first);
void Displaynbr(Mynbr* first);

int main(void)
{
    Mynbr* head = NULL;
    int choice = 0;

    while (choice!=5)
    {
        Menu();
        printf("Your choice : "); scanf("%d", &choice);
        choiceMenu(choice, head);
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void Menu()
{
    printf("\n1.Add number to the list\n");
    printf("2.Delete number from the list\n");
    printf("3.Search number in the list\n");
    printf("4.Display all the numbers from the list\n");
    printf("5.Exit\n");
}

void choiceMenu(int choice, Mynbr* first)
{
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        Addnumber(first);
        break;
    case 2:
        break;
    case 3:
        break;
    case 4:
        Displaynbr(first);
        break;
    case 5:
        break;
    }
}

Mynbr* Addnumber(Mynbr* first)
{
    printf("\n===Function to add a number===\n");
    Mynbr* head_nbr = first;
    if (!head_nbr)
    {
        head_nbr = (Mynbr*)malloc(sizeof(Mynbr));
        printf("Enter a number :"); scanf("%d", &(head_nbr->nbr));
        head_nbr->next = NULL;
    }
    return head_nbr;
}

void Displaynbr(Mynbr* first)
{
    printf("\n===Function to display number===\n");
    Mynbr* curr = first;
    if (curr->next)
    {
        printf("The number is : %d", curr->nbr);
        Displaynbr(first->next);
    }
}
```

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.5.2.2 Function calls 4 An argument may be an expression of any complete object type. In preparing for the call
to a function, the arguments are evaluated, and each parameter is assigned the value of the corresponding argument. 93) A function may change the values of its parameters, but these changes cannot affect the values of the arguments.* tl;dr: C is pass-by-value.

Comment: Off-topic: you don't need to cast the return of malloc

Answer (score 1):

You were not very far from it, but forgot one essential rule:
**when you change the value of a parameter in a function, the caller's value remains unchanged**.

So `AddNumber` (almost) correctly returns the new value of the list head address, but `choiceMenu` immediately discards it.

So here are some fixes:

`AddNumber` should be able to add a number to an empty or non empty list (NB: it currently leads to a LIFO):

```
Mynbr* Addnumber(Mynbr* first){
    printf("\n===Function to add a number===\n");
    Mynbr* head_nbr = first;
    head_nbr = (Mynbr*)malloc(sizeof(Mynbr));
    printf("Enter a number :"); scanf("%d", &(head_nbr->nbr));
    head_nbr->next = first;   // just link to initial head, be it null or not

    return head_nbr;
}
```

`choiceMenu` should not discard the new head - you can either return it to the caller like you do for `AddNumber` or use a double indirection:

```
void choiceMenu(int choice, Mynbr** first){
    switch (choice){
case 1:
    *first = Addnumber(*first);
    break;

case 2:
    break;
case 3:
    break;
case 4:
    Displaynbr(*first);
    break;
case 5:
    break;
    }
}
```

(do not forget to change the initial declaration and call it: `choiceMenu(choice, &head)`)

Last but not least, `DisplayNumber` incorrectly tests for `curr->next` instead of `curr`:

```
void Displaynbr(Mynbr* first){
    printf("\n===Function to display number===\n");
    Mynbr* curr = first;
    if (curr) {
        printf("The number is : %d", curr->nbr);
        Displaynbr(first->next);
    }
}
```

but this still displays *===Function to display number===* for each and every value in list. It is better here to use simple iteration instead of recursion:

```
void Displaynbr(Mynbr* first){
    printf("\n===Function to display number===\n");
    Mynbr* curr = first;
    while (curr) {
        printf("The number is : %d\n", curr->nbr);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
```

or using a `for` loop:

```
void Displaynbr(Mynbr* first){
    printf("\n===Function to display number===\n");
    Mynbr* curr;
    for (curr=first; curr != NULL; curr=curr->next) {
        printf("The number is : %d\n", curr->nbr);
    }
}
```

Recursive version could even be more concise by removing a useless local variable (thanks to @sokkyoku for the hint):

```
void Displaynbr(Mynbr* first){
    printf("\n===Function to display number===\n");
    if (first) {
        printf("The number is : %d", first->nbr);
        Displaynbr(first->next);
    }
}
```

---

If you want to change `AddNumber` to have a FIFO list, you need to add the new element at the end of the list. The code becomes:

```
Mynbr* Addnumber(Mynbr* first){
    printf("\n===Function to add a number===\n");
    Mynbr* head_nbr = malloc(sizeof(Mynbr));
    printf("Enter a number :"); scanf("%d", &(head_nbr->nbr));
    head_nbr->next = NULL;
    if (first == NULL) first = head_nbr;
    else {
        Mynbr* last = first;
        while (last->next != NULL) last = last->next;
        last->next = head_nbr;
    }
    return first;
}
```

But it would be more efficient in that case to keep a pointer to last element of the list instead of browsing the list to find it.

Comment: Please note that your changes to Addnumber result in the list being LIFO whereas FIFO might be expected.

Also, why bother with the `curr` variable at all in the recursive version of `Displaynbr`, you could directly use `first`

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help, but I want don't understand this part of code.Why next have been linked to first ?                    head_nbr->next = first;   // just link to initial head, be it null or not.    Moreover why you don't check if first in Addnumber() is NULL or not

Comment: @rony.stackoverflow: just imagine what happens in both cases, or carefully look at it under a debugger...

Answer (score 0):

The function has a prototype of

```
Mynbr* Addnumber(Mynbr* first)
```

It is called by `Addnumber(first)` in main. In main, the value pointed by the `first` pointer will be updated due to changes in the function. However, the first pointer itself will not be updated. i.e. the pointer will remain NULL. if it was NULL before.

To fix this you need to call the function in main like this

```
first = Addnumber(first);
```

Also, your `AddNumber` function needs to be fixed. You are not adding a number when for the second or larger element of the list.

```
Mynbr* Addnumber(Mynbr* first){
  printf("\n===Function to add a number===\n");
  Mynbr* head_nbr;
  head_nbr = malloc(sizeof(Mynbr));
  printf("Enter a number :"); scanf("%d", &(head_nbr->nbr));
  if (!first)
  {
    head_nbr->next = NULL;
  }
  else
  {
    head_nbr->next = first;
  }
  return head_nbr;
}
```

This function adds at the start of the list as suggested by the variable `head_nbr`. To add at the end, you will have to make appropriate modifications.

Comment: It's not actually in `main`, but the confusion is understandable given how the code was formatted. I've fixed the formatting